# How to get Authorization token in Youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube, request

I'm trying to simulation http request of youtube.When i delete a playlist item, i saw a param is authorization token hash by SAPISIDHASH in header [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAE69.png). How can i get it? Thank everyone!

Comment: Why not use the [official YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)? Following their docs, you'll easily be able to [obtain an OAuth token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) and [delete a playlist item](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete)

Comment: I know,but credentials of Youtube API have quotas.I like http request :v

Comment: Stuck on this same issue, did you ever figure out how to do it? I couldn't find this "SAPISISHASH" in any cookies, or in the html of the page